# Google map not loading when pressing back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using google map in my ionic app which loads fine when user opens the page for first time but after navigating to some other page and returning back to the map page google map wont show. I believe it has to do something with me using map script in index.html I tried injecting it in my map.html but to no success

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter"> 
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBJmvb_zA6sBKsF3w6wS5Xv4KDr0-hBBko&libraries=places"></script>
<ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

**map.html**

```
<ion-view>
 <ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class=" bar-royal">
     <ion-nav-title>
  <span>Find Hotels</span>
 </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar >
<ion-content  padding="true">

         <div class="list list-inset">
  <label class="item item-input">
    <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
   <input id="pac-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Location" data-tap-disabled="true" ng-change='disableTap()' ng-model="as">

  </label>
</div>
   <div id="map" style="height:50%; border:1px solid grey"></div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('MapController', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $location,$timeout, $http, customservice) {

$scope.fa = function(a, room_avail,prop_id) { 

    customservice.hotel_info={}
    angular.extend( customservice.hotel_info, {hotelName: a.innerHTML, roomsAvail: room_avail, propertyId : prop_id})
    $timeout(function () {
   $location.path('/hotel'); 
}, 0);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete)
function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 18,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(26.8611568,80.9356349),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);


  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {

    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
//
      var locurl = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getproperties"
      $http.post(locurl, {latitude : places[0].geometry.location.lat(0) , longitude : places[0].geometry.location.lng(0)
}).then(function(su){
          var locations = su.data.data.map(function (item) {
  return ['<span onclick="angular.element(this).scope().fa(this,'+item.room_avaialble+','+item.id+')">'+item.name+'</span>', item.latitude, item.longitude];
});
           var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
          // to set zoom after markers by sam
            // map.setZoom(14);
      },
        function(er){
          alert('er'+ JSON.stringify(er))
      })
      //  alert(places[0].geometry.location.lat(0));
      //
    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      if (!place.geometry) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }
      var icon = { 
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
         }
$scope.disableTap = function() {
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('pac-container');
angular.element(container).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
var backdrop = document.getElementsByClassName('backdrop');
angular.element(backdrop).attr('data-tap-disabled', 'true');
angular.element(container).on("click", function() {
document.getElementById('pac-input').blur();
});
};
})
```

Comment: Is your map gray after goBack ? You can try to call for `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` for your map

Comment: @jo no its blank.

Comment: How are you loading your map? Please show your controller or service you're loading from? Try using Ionic's lifecycle events ` $scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function( ){   loadMap()    }); `

Comment: no I am using `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete)`

Comment: Can you include the controller/service?

Comment: Ok I am editting my question

Comment: I would try and go with what `@yaboiduke` said and try to use `$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function( ){ yourfunction()  });`. Things like Domlisteners or Eventlisteners are not the 'Angular way.' http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: I was inserting `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete)`  inside `$ionicView.enter` which was not working but with `initAutocomplete()` it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging I found it

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.enter", function( ){
initAutocomplete() 
});
```